# AngularJs - ng-model in a SELECT

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wwno55hj/)

**Problem:**

I have a SELECT-element in my page, which is filled in with an `ng-repeat`. It also has a `ng-model` which has a default value.

When I change the value, the `ng-model` adapts, that's ok. But the dropdown-list shows an empty slot at launch, where it should have the item with the default value selected instead.

**Code**

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select class="form-control" ng-change="unitChanged()" ng-model="data.unit">
         <option ng-repeat="item in units" ng-value="item.id">{{item.label}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

With JS:

```
function myCtrl ($scope) {
    $scope.units = [
        {'id': 10, 'label': 'test1'},
        {'id': 27, 'label': 'test2'},
        {'id': 39, 'label': 'test3'},
    ]

        $scope.data = {
        'id': 1,
        'unit': 27
        }

};
```

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can use the [ng-selected](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected) directive on the option elements. It takes expression that if truthy will set the selected property.

In this case:

```
<option ng-selected="data.unit == item.id" 
        ng-repeat="item in units" 
        ng-value="item.id">{{item.label}}</option>
```

Demo

```js
angular.module("app",[]).controller("myCtrl",function($scope) {
    $scope.units = [
        {'id': 10, 'label': 'test1'},
        {'id': 27, 'label': 'test2'},
        {'id': 39, 'label': 'test3'},
    ]

        $scope.data = {
        'id': 1,
        'unit': 27
        }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select class="form-control" ng-change="unitChanged()" ng-model="data.unit">
         <option ng-selected="data.unit == item.id" ng-repeat="item in units" ng-value="item.id">{{item.label}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: This did the job: the other answers where helpful but I can't change the data-formats because they are used in other places and in other situations as well. This solved the problem without messing up the other data.

Comment: The angular docs for [`ngSelected`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected) say it shouldn't be used with `ngModel`.

Answer (score 17):

try the following code :

In your controller :

```
 function myCtrl ($scope) {
      $scope.units = [
         {'id': 10, 'label': 'test1'},
         {'id': 27, 'label': 'test2'},
         {'id': 39, 'label': 'test3'},
      ];

   $scope.data= $scope.units[0]; // Set by default the value "test1"
 };
```

In your page :

```
 <select ng-model="data" ng-options="opt as opt.label for opt in units ">
                </select>
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wwno55hj/3/)

Comment: It is a nice solution, but it wouldn't help me in my situation as I can't change the format of my data. I did copy the snippet for use in other situations in the future tho!

Comment: How do you show in HTML with data binding which option has been selected?

Comment: @StephenKuehl You have to set your model (var passed to ngModel) with the selected value you want.

Answer (score 7):

You dont need to define option tags, you can do this using the ngOptions directive: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

```
<select class="form-control" ng-change="unitChanged()" ng-model="data.unit" ng-options="unit.id as unit.label for unit in units"></select>
```

Comment: annoying part of this solution is that ng-model sets the target to what you are repeating in ng-options. Theres no way to set to a field of what are repeating (such as the id).

Answer (score 3):

> However, ngOptions provides some benefits such as reducing memory and increasing speed by not creating a new scope for each repeated instance. [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

Alternative solution is use `ng-init` directive. You can specify function that will be initialize your default data.

```
$scope.init = function(){
            angular.forEach($scope.units, function(item){
                if(item.id === $scope.data.unit){
                    $scope.data.unit = item;
                }
            });
        }
```

See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kiyanov/wwno55hj/4/)

Answer (score 2):

You can also put the item with the default value selected out of the ng-repeat like follow :

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select class="form-control" ng-change="unitChanged()" ng-model="data.unit">
        <option value="yourDefaultValue">Default one</option>
        <option ng-selected="data.unit == item.id" ng-repeat="item in units" ng-value="item.id">{{item.label}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

and don't forget the value atribute if you leave it blank you will have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Select's default value should be one of its value in the list. In order to load the select with default value you can use **ng-options**. A scope variable need to be set in the controller and that variable is assigned as **ng-model** in HTML's select tag.

View this plunker for any references:

http://embed.plnkr.co/hQiYqaQXrtpxQ96gcZhq/preview