# Angular modal bootstrap selected

Tags: angularjs, angular-bootstrap

I want to have a selected inside of my modal that depends on **$http** result.

This is my **template modal**

```
var templateModal = "<div class='modal-body'>" +
"<span>Orderer List </span>" +
    "<select ng-model='editable.orderer' ng-init='editable.orderer=\"{{editable.orderer_id}}\"'>" +
       "<option ng-repeat='x in ordererNames' value='{{x.ID}}'>{{x.post_title}}</option>" +
    "</select> <br/>" +
"</div>";
```

This is my script to open my modal

```
$scope.edit = function(data) {
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            template:templateModal,
            controller: managementModal,
            resolve: {
                items: function() {
                    return data;
                }
            }
        });
}
```

**Management Modal controller**

```
var managementModal = function($scope, $http, $uibModalInstance, items){
    $scope.names = items;
    $scope.editable = items;
    $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: Ajax_call.ajaxurl,
        params: {
            action: "orderer_names"
        }
    }).then(function(names){
        $scope.ordererNames = names.data;
        console.log($scope.ordererNames[0].ID)
    });

    $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: Ajax_call.ajaxurl,
        params: {
            action: "creator_names"
        }
    }).then(function(names){
        $scope.creatorNames = names.data;
    });

    $scope.cancel = function(){
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss(true);
    };
    $scope.update = function(){
        $uibModalInstance.close($scope.editable);
    };
};
```

This is what Ive tried so far Ive put an ng-init it doesnt selected if I put this but when I change the `{{editable.orderer_id}}` into a number it will be selected. I dont know why?

```
"<select ng-model='editable.orderer' ng-init='editable.orderer=\"{{editable.orderer_id}}\"'>" +
```

Also Ive tried **ng-selected** too

```
"<option ng-selected='editable.orderer_id == x.ID' ng-repeat='x in ordererNames' value='{{x.ID}}'>{{x.post_title}}</option>"
```

But still no luck

already read this answers

[ng-selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30048605/angularjs-ng-model-in-a-select) [ng-init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17645620/ng-selected-not-working-in-select-element)

EDITED

the JSON

```
[{
    "ID": 403,
    "post_title": "Kelly Johnson"
}, {
    "ID": 337,
    "post_title": "Staff"
}, {
    "ID": 287,
    "post_title": "Marie Cury"
}, {
    "ID": 278,
    "post_title": "Matugas"
},{
    "ID": 102,
    "post_title": "Antony Edison"
}]
```

Comment: Please post JSON data you load

Comment: @MaximShoustin done included the JSON

Comment: I see you load 2 objects: `creatorNames` and `orderNames`

Comment: Yes I think the problem is in the modal